# .NET Core WPF DI'd Named OptionsMonitor always null

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration

I have a .NET Core 3.1 WPF application, and I'm attempting to inject configuration values into a service in a lower layer (*Infrastructure*) through an `IOptionsMonitor<T>` using **Named Options**. Values are always populated as null.

Here's the file contents:

`appsettings.json`

```json
{
  "Repositories": {
    "Repo1": {
      "BaseUrl": "default1",
      "Fragment1": "defaultFragment1"
    },
    "Repo2": {
      "BaseUrl": "default2",
      "Fragment1": "defaultFragment2"
    }
  }
}
```

`appsettings.development.json`

```json
{
  "Repositories": {
    "Repo1": {
      "BaseUrl": "https://developmentRepo1.com",
      "Fragment1": "developmentFragment1"
    },
    "Repo2": {
      "BaseUrl": "https://developmentRepo2.com",
      "Fragment1": "developmentFragment2"
    }
  }
}
```

I have an **Environment Variable** which is `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` and it's set to `development`.

On the main `App.xaml.cs` I have this:

`App.xaml.cs`:

```cs
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
  var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.development.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

  Configuration = builder.Build();

  var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
  ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

  ServiceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

  var mainWindow = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PricingWizard>();
  mainWindow.Show();
}

private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddOptions();
  services.Configure<RepositoryConfiguration>(
    RepositoryConfiguration.Repo1Config, 
    Configuration.GetSection("Repositories:Repo1"));

  services.AddScoped<Infrastructure.SomeContext>();
}
```

My configuration `Class` looks something like this:

`RepositoryConfiguration.cs`:

```cs
public class RepositoryConfiguration
{
    public const string Repo1Config = "Repo1Config";

    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string Fragment1 { get; set; }
}
```

And the service in the layer below:

`SomeContext.cs`:

```cs
public class SomeContext : IDisposable
{
  private readonly RepositoryConfiguration configuration;

  public SomeContext(IOptionsMonitor<RepositoryConfiguration> configuration)
  {
    this.configuration = configuration.Get(RepositoryConfiguration.Repo1Config);
  }

  public void SomeMethod()
  {
    var url = configuration.BaseUrl;
  }
}
```

For some reason, both `BaseUrl` and `Fragment1` are always `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the appsettings files, make sure you are using the correct file and it contains the related value, and check the code where you call the SomeMethod() method.

According to your code, I have tested your code on my application, it seems that everything works well. Code as below:

Code in the SomeContext.cs:

```
public class SomeContext : IDisposable
{
    private readonly RepositoryConfiguration configuration;

    public SomeContext(IOptionsMonitor<RepositoryConfiguration> configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration.Get(RepositoryConfiguration.Repo1Config);
    } 
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 
    public string SomeMethod()
    {
        var url = configuration.BaseUrl;
        return url;
    }
}
```

Code in the App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; } 
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; } 
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

        Configuration = builder.Build();

        // Create a service collection and configure our dependencies
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

        // Build the our IServiceProvider and set our static reference to it
        ServiceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        var mainWindow = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppSettings)));
        services.AddScoped<ISampleService, SampleService>();
        services.Configure<RepositoryConfiguration>(RepositoryConfiguration.Repo1Config, Configuration.GetSection("Repositories:Repo1"));
        services.AddScoped<SomeContext>();
        services.AddTransient(typeof(MainWindow));
    }
}
```

Code in the MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ISampleService sampleService;
    private readonly AppSettings settings;
    private readonly SomeContext someContext;
    public MainWindow(ISampleService sampleService, IOptions<AppSettings> settings, SomeContext context)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.sampleService = sampleService;
        this.settings = settings.Value;
        this.someContext = context;

        lblBaseUrl.Content = context.SomeMethod();
    }

    private void ButtonExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

The appsettings.json content as below:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "StringSetting": "Value",
    "IntegerSetting": 42,
    "BooleanSetting": true
  },
  "Repositories": {
    "Repo1": {
      "BaseUrl": "https://developmentRepo1.com",
      "Fragment1": "developmentFragment1"
    },
    "Repo2": {
      "BaseUrl": "https://developmentRepo2.com",
      "Fragment1": "developmentFragment2"
    }
  }
}
```

It seems that the code works well on my side, screenshot as below:

[image]

Here is an article about [Using .NET Core 3.0 Dependency Injection and Service Provider with WPF](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2019/03/06/using-net-core-3-0-dependency-injection-and-service-provider-with-wpf/), you could check it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've managed to do a smaller version of my project with just these moving parts, and you're right... everything works fine! So it must mean there's something else going on solution-wise. I'll continue to dig deeper to try and find the issue...